# Altium Designer - Database library - Parameter: Component Type

Tags: altium, library

I use altium designer v14 and v15 with external component database (*.DbLib).
The external database is realized in SQL. Everything works fine except the manipulation of the component type. This parameter should also be set from database. As conjunction / relationship from database to altium, I take the name "Component Type". I think it's the wrong name / designation. Does anyone have a solution for this problem?

[image: Properties for schematic componen]
[image: Database library]

Comment: Maybe 'ComponentType' instead of 'Component Type'? Just a guess ...

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I forgot to say I have already tested "ComponentType" and "Type". But it doesn't work either.

Answer (score 2):

ComponentType = 'Standard' or 'Standard (No BOM)' works perfectly fine in SCH Filter to highlight those components my end and as such should be the right thing to set/get for your purpose.

Are you encoding/typing/what-evering the string value correctly? Altium is very persnickety with string types. (For one example in SCH Filter "Standard" would give an error, but 'Standard' works fine)

See also: [Altium TechDocs on ComponentType](http://techdocs.altium.com/display/ADRR/Schematic+Query+Functions#SchematicQueryFunctions-ComponentTypeField(Schematic))

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately this is one of the attributes the Altium Designer only saves
within the component model (e.g. the *.schlib file). Missing consistency.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that field is assignable from the database. There is a [limited set of reserved names](https://techdocs.altium.com/display/ADOH/Using+Components+Directly+from+Your+Company+Database#UsingComponentsDirectlyfromYourCompanyDatabase-ModelandParameterMapping) for automatic assignment available.

> If the database field name is one of the following reserved names, the corresponding model mapping entries will be automatically set in the Design Parameter field:

```
Description → [Description]
Footprint Ref → [Footprint Ref]
Footprint Path → [Footprint Path]
Footprint Ref n → [Footprint Ref n]
Footprint Path n → [Footprint Path n]
Library Ref → [Library Ref]
Library Path → [Library Path]
PCB3D Ref → [PCB3D Ref]
PCB3D Path → [PCB3D Path]
Sim Description → [Sim Description]
Sim Excluded Parts → [Sim Excluded Parts]
Sim File → [Sim File]
Sim Kind → [Sim Kind]
Sim Model Name → [Sim Model Name]
Sim Netlist → [Sim Netlist]
Sim Parameters → [Sim Parameters]
Sim Port Map → [Sim Port Map]
Sim Spice Prefix → [Sim Spice Prefix]
Sim SubKind → [Sim SubKind]
```